# Color SVG image with CSS

Tags: javascript, svg

Is there a way I can apply colors to SVG image as a whole? not going down to each path and circle and line I have and doing it one by one?

I tried to group my svg elements with

```
<g class="myImage">
```

and in the myImage class i put fill:red to make it apply to all the elements in that group, but that doesnt work!!

How can I make it so I can only apply a color once and it goes to the whole image or elements in a group?

--added code

This is my SVG file (this is just a sample, i know the circle repeats 3 times)

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="../css/logo.css" type="text/css"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">

<g class="logo">  
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="35%"/>
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="35%"/>
    <circle cx="50%" cy="50%" r="35%"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

and in my logo.css file i have a class

```
.logo {
    fill:red;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: *"I tried to group my svg file with..."*. Don't only tell us that you have tried something, but also show what you have tried.

Comment: Sorry my initial question did not post right, I just edited it

Comment: What you're trying should work. If you attach the entire file to the question we might be able to see what's wrong.

Comment: Firefox shows a big red circle. Is your UA doing something different?

Comment: Wow, I was trying all night last night and nothing was happening, I read your post today in the morning, tried again and it worked :| i really have no idea where I went wrong but it is working now, thank you very much! you should have posted as an answer so I can select you

Comment: Use the **defs** **use** construct.  Common properties are defined once in the defs block, individual properties are added further on when tags are used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it right. The fill should inherit from the `<g>` element and all the circles will be red, one on top of another. Firefox displays a big red circle.

Comment: I just double checked my settings and it worked, thank you for your reply